# Managing jobs and cron jobs in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, jobs, continuous-deployment

Can I manage jobs in K8S through its API requests?
I want my application to interact with the infrastructure through the API k8s.
For example, replace, change, delete jobs?
I did not find any useful literature, but I will be very grateful for it

Comment: [Kubernetes API Overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) in the Kubernetes documentation might be a good starting point.  You can modify any Kubernetes object using a REST call (subject to permission enforcement), and there are SDKs for most languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Can I manage jobs in K8S through its API requests?**

Yes, you can.

**I want my application to interact with the infrastructure through the API k8s. For example, replace, change, delete jobs?**

> The Kubernetes API is a resource-based (RESTful) programmatic interface provided via HTTP. It supports retrieving, creating, updating, and deleting primary resources via the standard HTTP verbs (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, GET).

Ref: [Kubernetes API Concepts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/)

**Recommendation:** Use Kubernetes [client library](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) for implementing your REST client.